# Applications not starting with sudo

Tags: linux-mint, sudo

I'm using Linux Mint 17 (Qiana) in my Oracle Virtual Box. Whenever I try to open an application with `sudo`, it is not working.

For eg. if I try to open sublime text editor using the command `sudo subl filename`, it is asking for the password. After entering the password, nothing is happening. But if I use `subl filename`, it is working and it prompts for password when you attempt to save it.

When I tried to open "Software Manager", it prompted password like this:

[image: Software Manager Popup]

Nothing happened when I entered the password. So I tried `mintinstall` from terminal, which again prompted for password like this:

[image: Password prompt]

After entering the password there, it outputs the following into terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintInstall/mintinstall.py", line 32, in <module>
    from widgets.pathbar2 import NavigationBar
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintInstall/widgets/pathbar2.py", line 1021, in <module>
    class PathBarThemeHuman:
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintInstall/widgets/pathbar2.py", line 1034, in PathBarThemeHuman
    animate = gtk.settings_get_default().get_property("gtk-enable-animations")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_property'
```

So, I'm greatly confused by these things. Please help.

Comment: It's probably a problem with X-AUTH-COOKIES or something. I'd propose an answer, but there are surely more knowledgeable Mint users out there.

Comment: What happens when you run `gksudo sublime` or `kdesu sublime`?

Comment: @pidosaurus No change in the behaviour while using them also :( However I'm doing the things in Ubuntu in which everything works perfectly :)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me: Changed the launcher for Software Manager

FROM:

```
gksu mintinstall
```

TO:

```
gksu -w mintinstall
```